# AngularJS Formly - dynamic change of field type

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap, angular-formly

What I wish to achieve is a single page (a form) used for both edit and display a record's data. I would like to have an edit button which would switch modes from edit to display and vice versa.

In terms of layout both modes looks the same.

In edit mode I have inputs/selects/typeaheads/multiple selects/datetime pickers etc. But in display mode values are displayed like in simple span. Something like that :)

So my question is: Is it possible to change field type after form is being rendered by formly? Any tips how to achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide an edit form and bind your data to each form so that changes on one of them will be visible on another. Here is a quick demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "demo";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-if="!edit">
    {{$parent.text}}
  </div>
  <div ng-if="edit">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.text" />
  </div>
  <button ng-click="edit = !edit">Edit</button>
</div>
```